# Postgres st_intersection points/polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am trying to use the ST_Intersection function to intersect points by county and find the counts by county, but I am having no luck.

```
SELECT counties.name,  
FROM counties INNER JOIN routes 
ON ST_Intersects(counties.geom, routes.geog1)
group by counties.name;
```

The error is telling me:  relation "counties" does not exist.

Can anyone help me fix my query. Should I be using the st_contains function?

*2nd day working with posgres/postgis so bear with me please!

Comment: if counties table is in another schema than public, then you need to specify your_schema.counties in the from clause. (or alter your search_path)

Comment: no they are both in public

Comment: What is result of `SELECT count(*) FROM counties GROUP BY counties.name`?

Comment: Also, `ST_Intersection` is not an aggregate function, so even if you PostGIS was finding the relation, I doubt this query would work.

Comment: SELECT count(*), name FROM public."Counties" group by name; this works fine-I just do not how 1. where to write the select script 2. how to use the intersect function 3. reference multiple tables who are in the same db, schema, public

Comment: I would undo that edit. I'm working on an answer.

Comment: am I approaching the problem wrong? should I be using the st_contains? I know I can easily do this in Arc with an intersect, dissolve+sum count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, it seems that you want to count routes by county. I assume `routes` is a `(MULTI)LINESTRING` and `counties` is a `(MULTI)POLYGON`. You have also indicated that they are both tables use the same SRID (4269).

The `ERROR: relation "counties" does not exist` is odd, but you say in the comments that `SELECT count(*), name FROM public."Counties" group by name;` is working. Are you running it *exactly* that way? Because if so, it looks like you defined the table using an upper case quoted identifier for `"Counties"`, which will *not* match `counties`, `"counties"`, or `"COUNTIES"`. In general, Postgres developers will avoid using upper case letters in identifier names for exactly this reason, in order to avoid having to exactly match case in double-quoted identifiers.

Assuming that's the issue, you should be able to get the count you want using:

```
SELECT counties.name, COUNT(*) AS route_count
FROM counties JOIN routes 
    ON ST_Intersects(counties.geom, routes.geog1)
GROUP BY counties.name;
```

The `ST_Intersection()` function you had in your original query is not an aggregate function, and therefore can't be used in the select list if you are using `GROUP BY`. If you actually want geometries of intersected routes in the result set, that is a different query.

Are routes completely contained by counties? If any routes cross a county border, they will be counted in *both* intersected counties. But switching to something like `ST_Contains` will *not* count them if they cross into neighboring county. Pick your poison.

Comment: okay thanks I am going to try this out. my routes table is not a linestring: it is has two separate geometry points (start and end) in the same table. Is that bad practice to have both start and end points in one table?

Comment: The practice should be whatever you can apply consistently. To me the name `routes` implies a linestring rather than a point. I guess you're using something like `geog1` as a start point and `geog2` as an endpoint? The query I wrote should still work. You might change to `ST_Contains` because I think `ST_Intersects` would count a point on a county border as intersecting both neighboring polygons. You should change your question to specify `routes.geog1` is a `POINT` geometry.

Comment: updated the SRID, did you query it worked!! literally I can't thank you enough been pounding at this for a while